# Is the orthocenter and incenter of a triangle the same point?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Although the orthoceneter and the incenter of a triangle are technically different things:

> The point in which the three altitudes of a triangle meet is called the orthocenter of the triangle.

> The point in which the three bisectors of the angles of a triangle meet is called the incenter of the triangle.

. . . Are they the same point?

Comment: No, unless bisectors are altitudes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not (though they can be). The incenter is, by construction, always inside the triangle, while the orthocenter can possibly be outside the triangle. (Consider a very obtuse triangle)

You can play with the orthocenter visually [here](http://www.mathopenref.com/triangleorthocenter.html), and the incenter [here](http://www.mathopenref.com/triangleincenter.html)

Answer (score 2):

They will coincide precisely when each bisector is an altitude--that is, for equilateral triangles.